# How to Hide Help Menu in SSRS 2017

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

is there any way to hide Help ( ? ) menu in SSRS 2017 Report Manager. Please see the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Any Suggestion/direction please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no option to hide **Help** Menu is SSRS 2017 Report Manager.

Everyone – Please vote to this suggestion so that product team could consider this request in upcoming release of SSRS.

**https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38452366-hide-help-menu-in-ssrs-2017**